# What is the purpose of a <af:declarativeComponent>?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have been through this [documentation on ADF declarative component](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_declarativeComponent.html) but not still not clear on the intent of such a component . I want to know what is the use of this guy and what are the scenarios where such a component could become useful ? Is this related to ui:composition in JSF2.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

af:declarativeComponent defines a dynamic declarative component and is used in ADF as a light weight form of encapsulating some UI logic. Think of it not as a template, but as a component that one can define without declaring a tag name (as for regular declarative components) and much lighter then a task-flow. When used you can pass parameters to such a component (including methods parameters since ADF 11.1.2). Such a component can also have a backing bean which executes in backing bean scope, so that if you have multiple instances of this component in a page you will have as many corresponding instances of the backing bean at the run-time, so the logic executed there will not interfere from one instance to another.

Comment: what do you mean declarative component ?

Comment: A declarative component is declared in a separate project and it's used with its own tag name. For example, this tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_40/jdtut_11r2_40.html) declares a component that is later used with the tag mc:myMenubar.

Comment: so all components declared via jsp tags are declarative ?

Answer (score 0):

ADF Declarative component is composite component created using predefined ADF Faces components. It can be included in a packaged jar file and can be included in any ADF Pages or Page Fragments as a reusable component.

Example: Create a declarative component for user login 
User Name [    af:InputText       ] 
Passwork  [    af:InputText       ] 
         SubmitButton

This component can be included in the login page in any application